# foreach label in specific column,C#

Tags: c#, foreach, tablelayoutpanel

I need to iterate on tableLayoutPanel and for each label where the column number equals 3 I need to clean its text.

I tried this, but it didn't work.
Can I do something?

```
foreach(Control c in this.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
    if( c is Label)
    {
      if(c.column==3)
           c.Text ="-";
    }
}
```

Comment: This shall work, just that you need to caste c to a label before get/set its text property.

Comment: @VishalSachdeva c dosent have the property column..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [GetColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of `TableLayoutPanel`

```
if (TableLayoutPanel1.GetColumn(c)== 3)
    c.Text = "-";
```